# Javascript function to remember what user had selected from a set of drop down menu options in his previous access

Tags: javascript

I'v an app in which i've 3 drop down menus which navigate to some specific page by those options of those three menus combination selected.
But every time the app is opened the user has to re-select that what he have selected in his previous visit.
So I want to give a feature like remembering the users choice.
Please provide some usefull code.
Thank You

Comment: Not sure exactly why you were downvoted, but it was probably because you're asking someone here to do work for you for free. This is an advice site. You're supposed to try it yourself, and when something doesn't work, you post what you've tried & ask for specific help with a particular issue. What you've posted is a specification, and not an uncommon one. If you really just want someone to do it for you, there are several gig sites where you can find a developer to write this for you for a few dollars.

Comment: you have to make some efforts toward solution of your problem. Start to write some code. SO is not automatic code-writing machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store data across sessions.

Comment: Thankyou Gilgamesh, I wil try and get back to you guys if i need more help.